# Отключить прокручивание на время перетаскивания

Tags: javascript

**Суть:** Пишу КанБан карточки и пытаюсь сделать возможность перетаскивания карточки даже если она находится далеко справа в скрытой части элемента.

**Попытки:** Попробовал сделать проверку на наличие нажатия по элементу карточки и отключать в этот момент прослушивания, но что-то не срабатывает.

**Задача:** Нужно чтобы при захвате и перетаскивании карточки в таблице канбан, прокрутка скриптом останавливалась, а когда отпускаешь карточку, то прокрутка зажатием по области таблицы возобновлялось.

```
var dragHandler = {
  lastClientX: 0,       
  start: function (e) {
      console.log('start');

      if (e.button == 0) {
          console.log('start button == 0');
          window.addEventListener('mousemove', dragHandler.drag);
          dragHandler.lastClientX = e.clientX;
          e.preventDefault();
      }     
   },
   end: function(e) {
       console.log('end');

       if (e.button == 0) {
           console.log('end button == 0');
           window.removeEventListener('mousemove', dragHandler.drag);
        } 

    },
    drag: function(e) {
        var delta = e.clientX - dragHandler.lastClientX;
        window.scrollTo(window.scrollX - delta, window.scrollY);
        dragHandler.lastClientX = e.clientX;
        e.preventDefault();         
    }
};


scroller_content.addEventListener('mousedown', dragHandler.start);
scroller_content.addEventListener('mouseup', dragHandler.end);
$('.drag-item-suppilo-status').on("mousedown", function(e) {
    console.log('взял элемент');    
});
$('.drag-item-suppilo-status').on("mouseup", function(e) {
    console.log('бросил элемент');
});
$( "<?=$options?>" ).sortable({
    connectWith: ".suppilo_status_block",
    cancel: ".title_status_suppilo, .nav, .dropdown, .dropdown-menu, .divider-d, .border-b",
    items: 'li.kaban-block', // Указывает какие элементы в группе могут быть отсортированы. 
    handle: '.drag-item-suppilo-status', //Указывает элемент, при щелчке на который начнется перетаскивание. 
    helper:'original', // Устанавливает вид элемента помощника  original или clone
    opacity:1, // прозрачность перетаскиваемого элемента
    cursor: 'n-resize', // вид курсора при нажатии
    revert: 'true', // эффект вставляния перетаскиваемого элемента
    placeholder:"ui-state-highlight",
    start: function (){
        console.log('start drag');
    },
    beforeStop: function (event, ui){
        console.log('beforeStop');
        //$('.scrollWrapper').css('overflow','hidden');
        var id_status = ui.item.parent().data('id-status');
        var id_order = ui.item.data('id');
        console.log(''+ui.item.data('id')+' из '+ui.item.parent().data('id-status')+'');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/update_order.php?vid=leads',
            data: "id=status&value="+id_status+"&id_order="+id_order+"&id_staff=<?=$userdata['id_staff'];?>&id_cabinet=<?=$id_cabinet;?>",
                success: function(data){$("div#response").html(data);},
                error: function(data){$("div#response").html("Error");}
        }); 
    }       
}).disableSelection();
```

Comment: чтобы запретить прокрутку просто `overflow: hidden`

Comment: @Август а можно как-то по подробнее куда добавить? Что-то я не совсем понимаю, как вы это видите...

Comment: да, конечно. Вам же нужно просто временно *нейтрализировать* событие скролла и запретить странице скроллиться? если да, то просто задавайте стиль `overflow: hidden` тому блоку, которые у Вас скролится. после этого ни скролл, ни событие `scroll` срабатывать не будут

Comment: @Август совсем нельзя запрещать, так как например карточку иногда нужно будет перетащить в блоки которые справа или слева и стандартная прокрутка нужна. Нужно запретить прокрутку именно сприптом который указан, а стандартная прокрутка должна работать.

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему простым способом! К контейнеру, который нужно прокручивать и который содержит в себе карточки канбана добавил класс `scroller-active`, который стоит по умолчанию. В коде отвечающем за прокрутку сделал проверку на наличие класса `scroller-active`, если он есть, то прокрутка по нажатию работает, если нет, то не работает.

Чтобы выключить прокрутку скриптом на время перетаскивания, но не отключать браузерную прокрутку, просто добавил отслеживания событий `mousedown` и `mouseup`. Когда вы хватаете карточку, которую нужно перетащить, то убираем класс `scroller-active`, если отпускаем карточку возвращаем класс на место.

Все.

Код:

```
var dragHandler = {
                lastClientX: 0,

                start: function (e) {
                    console.log('start');


                        if (e.button == 0) {
                            console.log('start button == 0');
                            scroller_content.addEventListener('mousemove', dragHandler.drag);
                            dragHandler.lastClientX = e.clientX;
                            e.preventDefault();
                        } 

                },
                end: function (e) {
                    console.log('end');
                        if (e.button == 0) {
                            console.log('end button == 0');
                            scroller_content.removeEventListener('mousemove', dragHandler.drag);                        
                        } 

                },
                drag: function (e) {

                    if($('.scroller-right-content').hasClass('scroller-active')){
                        var delta = e.clientX - dragHandler.lastClientX;
                        window.scrollTo(window.scrollX - delta, window.scrollY);
                        dragHandler.lastClientX = e.clientX;
                        e.preventDefault();
                    }

                }
            };
            scroller_content.addEventListener('mousedown', dragHandler.start);
            scroller_content.addEventListener('mouseup', dragHandler.end);



            $('.drag-item-suppilo-status').on("mousedown", function(e) {
                $('.scroller-right-content').removeClass('scroller-active');

            });
            $('.drag-item-suppilo-status').on("mouseup", function(e) {
                $('.scroller-right-content').addClass('scroller-active');
            });



            $( "<?=$options?>" ).sortable({
                connectWith: ".suppilo_status_block",
                cancel: ".title_status_suppilo, .nav, .dropdown, .dropdown-menu, .divider-d, .border-b",
                items: 'li.kaban-block', // Указывает какие элементы в группе могут быть отсортированы. 
                handle: '.drag-item-suppilo-status', //Указывает элемент, при щелчке на который начнется перетаскивание. 
                helper:'original', // Устанавливает вид элемента помощника  original или clone
                opacity:1, // прозрачность перетаскиваемого элемента
                cursor: 'n-resize', // вид курсора при нажатии
                revert: 'true', // эффект вставляния перетаскиваемого элемента
                placeholder:"ui-state-highlight",
                start: function (){
                    console.log('start drag');
                  },

                beforeStop: function (event, ui){
                    console.log('beforeStop');
                    var id_status = ui.item.parent().data('id-status');
                    var id_order = ui.item.data('id');
                    console.log(''+ui.item.data('id')+' из '+ui.item.parent().data('id-status')+'');
                 $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: '/update_order.php?vid=leads',
                        data: "id=status&value="+id_status+"&id_order="+id_order+"&id_staff=<?=$userdata['id_staff'];?>&id_cabinet=<?=$id_cabinet;?>",
                        success: function(data){$("div#response").html(data);},
                        error: function(data){$("div#response").html("Error");}
                    }); 
                } 

            }).disableSelection();
```

Comment: я как раз собирался покушать и сесть за Ваш вопрос, но ладно.. тогда мои поздравления)

Comment: @Август может ваше решение лучше будет. Написали бы =)